# Warning when following sensor noise model tutorial: [Wrn] [msgs.cc:1808] Conversion of sensor type[imu] not suppported

Tags: gazebo-sensor, gazebo-tutorial, gazebo-7

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am using Gazebo version : 7.13.1
Link to tutorial : http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=sensor_noise&cat=sensors#IMUnoise

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/19762/i-am-following-sensor-noise-model-tutorial-given-in-gazebo-tutorials-for-inserting-imu-sensor-on-my-robot.-i-am-getting-this-warning-:-%5Bwrn%5D-%5Bmsgs.cc:1808%5D-conversion-of-sensor-type%5Bimu%5D-not-suppported.-how-to-get-rid-of-this-error-?/) by [pk](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5254/pk/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 11 on 2018-06-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

This warning is coming from inside Gazebo, there's no way to get rid of it, unless you contribute with a pull request implementing the conversion ;)

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2018-06-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pk](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5254/pk/) on 2018-06-19**:
I am new to gazebo. How to implement conversion ?

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2018-06-19**:
Looks like you're in luck, the conversion already exists on newer Gazebo versions. You could port it to the gazebo7 branch if you're interested in contributing: https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/cc5101392ae32616bf9bf39b6fc051104836aeb1/gazebo/msgs/msgs.cc?fileviewer=file-view-default#msgs.cc-1860

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2018-06-19**:
Here are some tutorials on how to contribute: http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?cat=guided_a&tut=guided_a1